# Get recent facebook comments left on wordpress site

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, comments

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}

Id like to display comments made on my site using the facebook comments widget, and using the link above.

Is there a way to turn this into query, with the most recent post url to have a facebook comment displayed. Also the avatar and the comments made there?

And if you will suggest to use plugins, theres nothing in there that work, facebook for wordpress widget to do this has a error.

And if you will ask why not search for forums. I did both here and wordpress answers all are just about fetching comments on a facebook page but not facebook.?

I hope somebody has done this already.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484008/how-to-display-recent-comments-from-facebook-comments-social-plugin?rq=1

Comment: Then how do you pull all comments from the site posts? Its not done according to the question and i cant reply there anymore.

Comment: You can use this widget to show recent Facebook Comments made all over your website in the widget area of your choice. https://www.heateor.com/facebook-comments-moderation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you may be looking for.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments?access_token=XXX
```

Comment: No i already have that i want to display the comments made from that like a recent comments widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and change {object-id} By the post ID

https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}/comments?summary=1&filter=toplevel?access_token=XXX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this can fulfill your needs. You can use this widget to show recent Facebook Comments made all over your website in the widget area of your choice. https://www.heateor.com/facebook-comments-moderation